# No disk driver for OS install, server 16.04 LTS in Hyper-V

Tags: 16.04, drivers, disk, 32-bit

I'm trying to get 32-bit server 16.04 LTS installed as a Gen 1 VM in Hyper-V and running into an issue I've never had before: the installer cannot find disk drivers, so I can't partition and install the OS anywhere. I've got a fixed-size 150 GB vhd set on an IDE controller. I'm assuming my issue is coming from trying to install 32-bit, as I've never seen this with 64-bit versions of 18.04. I've been googling for two days and nobody else seems to have this issue.

Can anyone point me towards which driver I should be using, or help figure out where the issue lies? I'm stuck using 32-bit per the software I'm stuck using, otherwise I'd go with what I know works.

Answer (score 0):

On Long Term Support (LTS) releases, use the latest virtual Hardware Enablement (HWE) kernel for up to date Linux Integration Services.

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask you a question, that is important for us to help you with na answer: Why are you using the 16.04 LTS and not the 18.04 LTS? There is a netinst 32-bit version of it [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/?_ga=2.78722512.579212502.1552488240-1884583121.1552488240). You can also improvise with the Desktop 32-bit version [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/bionic/daily-live/current/).